# Identify Excel min and max dates, per day

Tags: excel, datetime

I am finding good information here on working with dates, but so far I have not had any luck finding exactly what I want to do.

I have a column that is responsible for generating a date/time stamp for each entry in a particular row, and that date/time column spans *across days*.

Here is an example of the date/time column:

April 04, 2018 07:45

April 04, 2018 12:51

April 04, 2018 14:39

April 04, 2018 22:10

April 05, 2018 11:36

April 05, 2018 18:22

April 06, 2018 11:30

April 06, 2018 11:29

April 06, 2018 22:45

April 07, 2018 10:48

April 08, 2018 04:30

April 08, 2018 13:14

To be sure, these *are* actual Excel date/time entries that are formatted and conform to Excel such that Datetime functions will work with them.

There can be (and are) numerous entries per day, each row contains a datetime stamp, and I specifically need to designate the first entry and last entry for each specific day.

Here is an output example (from the data above) that hopefully will clear up any confusion around my question.

April 04, 2018 07:45   **First**

April 04, 2018 12:51

April 04, 2018 14:39

April 04, 2018 22:10   **Last**

April 05, 2018 11:36   **First**

April 05, 2018 18:22   **Last**

April 06, 2018 11:30   **First**

April 06, 2018 11:29

April 06, 2018 22:45   **Last**

April 07, 2018 10:48   **First**

April 08, 2018 04:30   **First**

April 08, 2018 13:14   **Last**

I recognize the 7th doesn't have a logical last date, but I figure I can address with with error handling once I am able to address the initial issue.

The function MIN in this case =MIN(A2:A64) would just return April 04, 2018 07:45, which is correct for that day, but *only* because it is the earliest among *all of the dates*, and *not specific to the day itself.*

Any ideas how I can find the min and max *within days* rather than *across days*?

Thank you in advance!

-John

Answer (score 0):

I wish you had posted your data sample in a more universal date format, i.e. no comma before the year and the month as a number. I spent twice as much time cleaning up the data to get this into a date/time stamp than I  needed to work out the answer.

If the data is sorted, then you can use this formula:

```
=IF(INT(A3)>INT(A2),"first",IF(INT(A3)<>INT(A4),"last",""))
```

Row 1 must be blank and the formula starts in row 2.

[image]